# Close app until certain date

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a question for you all. I have my app but I need it can open only until some day. For example, if the user opens the app today, it shall close itself because I just want to open until 11/12, got it?

Hope I have explained what I need to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use Alarm Manager

Comment: What have you tried to do ? don't expect people to give you the code ready for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to make a trial application, right?

There are many ways, I've only 2 ways currently:

1. **Using local persistence data**

   - Save date time when user first launch the app in preference or SQLite.
   - Make a constant for how many days user can use the app, like **MAX_USAGE**
   - Each time user run the app, check current time with the previous date time. If the difference is greater than **MAX_USAGE**, close the activity.

```
pros:
  - Easy to implement.
  - Work offline.

cons:
  - User can change the current time of his device.
  - User can change the MAX_USAGE if he know how to dissamble the code.
```

2. **Using server**

   - When user first launch the app, send user id and current time to server.
   - Make a constant for how many days user can use the app, like **MAX_USAGE**
   - Each time user run the app, check current time with the previous date time for user id in server. If the difference is greater than **MAX_USAGE**, close the activity.

```
pros:
  - User can't change the MAX_USAGE because it reside in server.  
  - More reliable for checking if app has been tempered or not.

cons:
  - Hard to implement.
  - Need to maintanance both user app and server.
  - Need to check for server availability.
  - Don't work offline.
```

Comment: Imo, using a server is more reliable and un-hackable

Comment: @Bhargav You're right, I've incorporated your comment in the answer.